# Keyboard shortcut to lock the screen on macOS 10.14 Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, screen-lock

Is there a keyboard shortcut to lock the screen on macOS 10.14 Mojave like <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or something easy without setting up Hot Corners/Spaces etc.

The app [Lock Me Now](https://github.com/IGRSoft/LockMeNow) used to work fine till maOS High Sierra, but isn't starting up on macOS Mojave. It is showing this popup as soon as I try to run it:

[image]

Is there an app that works on Mojave which helps to customize the lock keyboard shortcut to Command+L? I am used to using Command+L on windows and older Mac OS (using "Lock me now" app).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built-in keyboard shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to lock the screen.

The command is also accessible via  → Lock Screen in the Menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the windows keyboard, try the below shortcut to lock MAC machine, which is worked for me.
**Cmd+Ctrl+Q  = To lock the Mac machine using windows keyboard.**

Comment: This keyboard shortcut also works on Apple keyboards. :)

Comment: How does this differ from the answer already given?